# Does not display the correct error message -JSP

Tags: jsp, session, setattribute, getattribute

I have set an Error page in which I want to appear this message, when I call the Page2 without setting in object_user a value. But when I call it, the message which I get is "null" and no my expected message.

What is the problem?

**Page1**

```
 <% session.setAttribute("user_object", username);  %>
 <jsp:forward page="Page2.jsp" />
```

**Page 2**

```
 <%
if (session.getAttribute("user_object") == null) {
throw new Exception("For login press <a href='LoginForm.jsp'>here</a>"); 
                 }
 %>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: whats your error page code?

Comment: The error page code is correct because it runs for other cases of error. In this specific case does not print the correct message

Comment: can we see it please? and what does it print in this case?

Comment: <% String message = exception.getMessage(); %>
 <%= message %>

Comment: It prints "For login press <a href='LoginForm.jsp'>here</a>"

Comment: well it prints correctly isnt it?

Comment: No. this is the expected message. it prints "null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96664/discussion-between-mavroscy-and-nancy).